# How to insert value of single selection into column of table

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have an Oracle adf and javadeveloper.

I drag view from datacontrol and drop into jsf page as table.

I drag another view from datacontrol and drop into jsf page as single selection and drop button into page.

My intention is that after clicking a button ,the value of single selection be inserted into field of the table.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

User, tell us your Jdev version, please!

What do you mean by

> value of single selection be inserted into field of the table.

Do you mean into every row in the table or just the one currently selected in the table?
If you only want to insert the value of the one row into one row of the other table it's simply a declarative method. If you wasn't to change every row of the table you have to implement a method in the application module and call it the button click.

Timo